# Quick sort stack overflow error

Tags: java, sorting, stack-overflow, quicksort

I've been working on a project that requires empirical analysis of the elapsed time of a selection sort, quick sort, and java's quick sort(arrays.sort). Everything works fine in the program except for when it reaches my user created quick sort there is a problem with the execution and it gives a stack overflow error. I'm sure there is a recursive call problem in here, but I'm not sure where or how to fix it. The code for the quicksort method can be found below.

```
public void quickSort(int[] list) {
    quickSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
  }

  private void quickSort(int[] list, int first, int last) {
    if (last > first) {
      int pivotIndex = partition(list, first, last);
      quickSort(list, first, pivotIndex - 1);
      quickSort(list, pivotIndex + 1, last);
    }
  }

  /** Partition the list[first..last] */
  private int partition(int[] list, int first, int last) {
    int pivot = list[first]; // Choose the first element as the pivot
    int low = first + 1; // Index for forward search
    int high = last; // Index for backward search

    while (high > low) {
      // Search forward from left
      while (low <= high && list[low] <= pivot)
        low++;

      // Search backward from right
      while (low <= high && list[high] > pivot)
        high--;

       // Swap two elements in the list
      if (high > low) {
        int temp = list[high];
        list[high] = list[low];
        list[low] = temp;
      }
    }

    while (high > first && list[high] >= pivot)
      high--;

    // Swap pivot with list[high]
    if (pivot > list[high]) {
      list[first] = list[high];
      list[high] = pivot;
      return high;
    }
    else {
      return first;
    }
  }






/*Main*/

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lab5  sortLab = new  Lab5 ();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.print("Enter the size of the data set N = ");
    n = input.nextInt();

    int[] array1 = new int[n];
    int[] array2 = new int[n];
    int[] array3 = new int[n];
    int[] array4 = new int[n];

    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){ 
    if (rnd.nextDouble() < 0.5) // positive integers
      array1[i]=(1 + rnd.nextInt(100));
    else                     // negative integers
      array1[i]=((1 + rnd.nextInt(100)) * -1);
    }//for

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array2, 0, n);
    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array3, 0, n);

//printing nanoseconds only

long startTime = System.nanoTime(); //start clock
sortLab.quickSort(array2);//call method to be measured
long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime ; //stop clock - start       clock gives elapsed time
System.out.printf("\tTime elapsed for our quick sort: = %f",  ((double)elapsedTime)/Math.pow(10,9));

System.arraycopy(array4, 0, array1, 0, n);
System.arraycopy(array4, 0, array2, 0, n);
System.arraycopy(array4, 0, array3, 0, n);

  }//for


  }//main
```

Comment: You have no condition for breaking your recursion...You need a return in there

Comment: @JesseShellabarger I don't think that's the problem. His `if` should simply not execute and essentially `return void` when it fails.

Comment: @River Yup, you're right. Read the code too quickly. My bad.

Comment: Do you have an example of a list causing an overflow?

Comment: The code runs fine for me and produces no errors.

Comment: Here is the main, maybe this will help....

Comment: I added the main to the bottom of the code above, still not sure why I keep getting the stack overflow...

Comment: Also here is the error that occurs...                                                           Enter the size of the data set N = 20000
 Time elapsed for our quick sort: = 0.034526Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at lab5.Lab5.quickSort(Lab5.java:15)
 at lab5.Lab5.quickSort(Lab5.java:16)
 at lab5.Lab5.quickSort(Lab5.java:16)